# Columns not aligning Correctly

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a news section that is set to display a total of 12 news items, 4 on each row, summing 3 rows. However, they don't seem to align properly. Please see the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOIrN.jpg)

Comment: Could you post the html and css to reproduce that page?

Comment: Thanks Dan for reaching out, can share the url if thats okay ?

Comment: Yeah. Post the URL and that will make it easier to figure out.

Comment: url: http://damitavictoria.com/ completely non responsive both on tablets and phone

Comment: Looks good on my end. I'm running Window 7 and I tried it in the latest versions of Chrome, Edge, Firefox, and IE. What browser are you seeing the issue in?

Comment: Nevermind. I see what's going on. Going to post an answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot below, you'll see a div highlighted with the classes `.row` and `.row-products`

Make that row a row based flex-layout and you'll get what you're looking for.

```
.row-products {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12{
    float:left
}
```

remove `float:left` and add `display:inline:block;`

use Bootstrap grid :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/